# How to get ASP.NET running on Apache on CentOS 7?

Tags: asp.net, linux, apache-http-server, mono, centos

I successfully installed Apache, Mono, XSP Server and MonoDevelop on a CentOS 7 machine, basically following http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#centos-fedora-and-derivatives (with added `yum install -y xsp`, and `yum install -y monodevelop`. Mono Develop works and I can create and run ASP.NET websites with it (via XSP Server).

But I need to integrate Mono with Apache. To do this I installed `mod_mono` (`yum install -y mod_mono`) and created a configuration for a test application via http://go-mono.com/config-mod-mono/. I changed the mono server version to 4 and added granting open access:

```
Alias /mono-test "/srv/www/mono-test"
MonoServerPath mono-test "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4"
MonoDebug mono-test true
MonoApplications mono-test "/mono-test:/srv/www/mono-test"
<Location "/mono-test">
  Allow from all
  Order allow,deny
  MonoSetServerAlias mono-test
  SetHandler mono
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip dont-vary
  # Allow open access:
  Require all granted
</Location>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
</IfModule>
```

I placed the file in `/etc/httpd/confd` with the name `x-mono-test.conf`, to be sure it is loaded after the default `mod_mono.conf` (content see at the end of this question).

The problem is that accessing a test aspx file in the Apache application (http://localhost/mono-test/test.aspx) results in a HTTP 503 - Service Unavailable. The Apache error log remains empty.

I would like to know what could be wrong or how I could find the source of this issue.

Content of `mod_mono.conf`:

```
<IfModule !mod_mono.c>
    LoadModule mono_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_mono.so
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Powered-By "Mono"
</IfModule>

AddType application/x-asp-net .aspx
AddType application/x-asp-net .asmx
AddType application/x-asp-net .ashx
AddType application/x-asp-net .asax
AddType application/x-asp-net .ascx
AddType application/x-asp-net .soap
AddType application/x-asp-net .rem
AddType application/x-asp-net .axd
AddType application/x-asp-net .cs
AddType application/x-asp-net .vb
AddType application/x-asp-net .master
AddType application/x-asp-net .sitemap
AddType application/x-asp-net .resources
AddType application/x-asp-net .skin
AddType application/x-asp-net .browser
AddType application/x-asp-net .webinfo
AddType application/x-asp-net .resx
AddType application/x-asp-net .licx
AddType application/x-asp-net .csproj
AddType application/x-asp-net .vbproj
AddType application/x-asp-net .config
AddType application/x-asp-net .Config
AddType application/x-asp-net .dll
DirectoryIndex index.aspx
DirectoryIndex Default.aspx
DirectoryIndex default.aspx
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss one set in the configuration of apache with mono. I strongly suggest you to check this guide is for Ubuntu. I tried and it works fine with xsp and apache. I test some examples and work fine for everything except WCF (svc). Apparently, that support it still with a lot of problems in mono 2.10.

http://www.bgsoftfactory.net/run-asp-net-mvc-4-with-mysql-on-linux/

I think the problem could be that the virtual host is not active. But, that is a simple hunch.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: If anyone is working on WCF in Linux. I strongly recommend to check this project https://github.com/dotnet/wcf It is currently in development and have several persons collaborating constantly.